# Tableau sum by condition

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data like this

`Date                    Temperature  Load
2017-08-05 7:45:00 PM   10            5
2017-08-05 7:46:00 PM   10            4
2017-08-05 7:47:00 PM   10            2
2017-08-05 7:48:00 PM   10            1
2017-08-05 7:49:00 PM   10            5
.........`

In Tableau, how can I sum the `Load` by hours and plot scatters?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the behavior/final format you're expecting with the scatter-plot?  As well has how you expect the Temperature field to be aggregated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would drag SUM(Load) onto Rows and AVG(Temperature) onto columns and discrete hour of Date onto Details. That would give you a scatter plot like

[image]